# Filter values with left function instead of like "x%"

Tags: sql

I was told that the `LIKE` function uses too much of the PC's processor and was suggested to instead use the `LEFT` function to filter the values.

This is the query that I am currently using:

```
select w.fecha_key, sum(saldo) Saldo_Suma
FROM fact_balance_comprobacion w 
     inner join dim_con_cuenta_contable s 
     on s.cuenta_contable_key = w.cuenta_contable_key 
where cuenta_contable like '4%' or cuenta_contable like '5%'
GROUP BY w.fecha_key;
```

Comment: The `LIKE` is not causing the performance issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your current `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE
    cuenta_contable LIKE '4%' OR
    cuenta_contable LIKE '5%'
```

You *could* replace with `LEFT` here as follows:

```
WHERE
    LEFT(cuenta_contable, 1) = '4' OR
    LEFT(cuenta_contable, 1) = '5'
```

That being said, I actually don't expect that `LEFT` would offer much performance advantage over `LIKE` here.  The reason is that your calls to `LIKE` are anchored to the start of the string, so they should only have to walk down the string once, similar to what `LEFT` would be doing.  An inefficient call to `LIKE` would be something like:

```
WHERE cuenta_contable LIKE '%4%'
```

In this case, the database has to check for 4 present anywhere in the string.